# I have/will have time tomorrow?

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense, future-time

- > I have time tomorrow.
- > I **will** have time tomorrow.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both. *I have* is the enduring present tense used to describe a situation that obtains now and will probably continue to do so. *I will have* is the simple future tense.

Comment: It is perhaps clearer to say that the present tense is often used to describe a situation that is confidently **expected** to obtain at some time in the future. 'I fly to Rio on Thursday.' See [edufind.com: simple present – future events](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Both are correct, but most proffered one is

**I have time tomorrow.**

This means, I have time ***definitely***. On the other hand It is expressed with a *confirmation.*

- [Subject] = I
- [Verb] = have
- [Object] = time
- [Predicate] = tomorrow

**I will have time tomorrow.**

This means, I am ***not sure*** that I have time or not. On the other hand I have time *sometimes*.

- [Subject] = I
- [Auxiliary Verb] = will
- [Verb] = have
- [Object] = time
- [Predicate] = tomorrow

Comment: Did you mean: the most _preferred_ one is...? Also, what evidence do you have that one of these is more common or preferred than the other? Lastly, do you see any difference in meaning? Your parsing doesn't really help with that.

Comment: There are two different meanings for those two.

Comment: I think if your answer explained the difference between the two, it might be getting more upvotes than downvotes.